# How can I have one @Html.dropdownfor drive another in the MVC 3 View?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

- I've got two types of data I'm dealing with:  "ClassType" and
  "Disciplines".  ClassType is the master data type that drives the
  secondary Disciplines.  The idea is that each ClassType will have a
  number of Disciplines assigned to them.  So, what I'm trying to do is
  have Disciplines depend on the selection of CLassType.  How would I
  do that with the Microsoft MVC 3 framework in the view?  The
  following is my Controller/Model/View code:

  ```
  CONTROLLER:
  ```

  public ActionResult Create()
      {
          List c_types = new List();
          List disc = new List();

  ```
      c_types = m_activeContract.getCtypeList();
      disc = m_activeContract.getDisciplineList();
      // TODO:  fetch from repository or database

      var model = new ExampleDocument
      {
          ClassTypes = a_modes,
          Disciplines = disc
      };

      return View(model);
  } 


  MODEL:

  public int ClassTypeId { get; set; }
  public int DisciplineId { get; set; }
  public List<ClassType> ClassTypes { get; set; }
  public List<Discipline> Disciplines { get; set; }

  VIEW:

  @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Example") ) {
          <p>Class Type: 
          @Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.ClassTypeId,
                   new SelectList(Model.ClassTypes, "Id", "Name"))</p>
          <p>Discipline:
          @Html.DropDownListFor( x => x.DisciplineId,
                  new SelectList(Model.Disciplines, "Id", "Name")) </p>
          <p>
              <input type="submit" value="Create" />
          </p>
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In your controller, populate your list of Discipline Type entities based on the ClassTypeId using your business rule.
2. Also, add a controller action that gets a json result of Discipline Type entities for a passed in class type id.
3. In your view, add a javascript event on the change of the Class Type field.  In that event, use an ajax call back to the controller action that returns a list of Discipline types based on the class id, and use that to populate your Discipline Type dropdown.  This way, when a user selects a different Class Type, the list of DisciplinesTypes changes.

Answer (score 0):

> > ClassType drives the secondary Disciplines

so i think u have to do ajax call in javascript on drop down of ClassType and populate data in Discipline